# How do you navigate through functions within functions in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Once you are in a function, How would you be able to navigate from function to function within your original function? (I wrote pseudo code because I do not know how to accomplish this)

```
def main():
    do...
    if something == 1
       access function(Success)
    elif something == 2
       access function(Failed)
    elif something == 3
       end script
    else
       print "choose a proper option idiot"
def menuSuc():
    print 1) How many total requests (Code _____)
    print 2) How many requests from _____ (IPs starting with 142.204)
    print 3) How many requests for isomaster-1.3.13.tar.bz2
    print q) Return to Main Menu
def menuFai():
    print 1) How many total failed requests (Codes _____)
    print 2) How many invalid requests for wp-login.php
    print 3) List the filenames for failed requests for files in /apng/assembler/data
    print q) Return to Main Menu

def success(argv):
    do.....    
    print menuSuc
    print information 
def failed(argv):
    do.....    
    print menuFai
    print information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function you want to use inside the function. I would avoid calling a function a function in Python code. Don't forget that in Python 3 print is a function--add "()" around the quotes.

```
def main():
if something == 1:
   Success() # to access function(Success)
elif something == 2:
   Failed()
elif something == 3:
   return print("script Done")
else:
   print("choose a proper option") # no need to call people names :)
```

main()